# What does the word よれん mean?

Tags: grammar, words, dialects, manga

Here is the sentence:

> おおっ　くせえのう…　おらあぶた小屋だけはマスクなしではそばにも**よれん**わい。

It is probably said by Kansai speaker which I'm not certain.

I understand that よれん or よれない means 'not to get twisted'. But I think it would be conflicted because if he is coming near pig pen without wearing a mask, his face should be getting twisted because of stinky smell.

Comment: Please ask your extra question separately.

Comment: Which part in …のう、…わい looks Tohoku-ben?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

よれ (wrinkle) is a different verb to よれん. 
よれん is from よらない which is the negative of よる (寄る come near).

> おおっ　くせえのう…　おらあぶた小屋だけはマスクなしではそばにもよれんわい。
>   
> Oh, so smelly... Pig house is the only place I can't go near without a mask.

Answer (score 2):

He is basically saying that the pig pen stinks and won't go near it (without a mask, to be more precise).

「よれん」means in this case not to go near the pig pen. It does not mean 'not to get twisted'. When referring to the mask, he just means that a mask would be able to get him near a pig pen.
In this instance 「おらあ」means, he is talking about himself.

I should also point out that this type of talk would be from an older man or the story that it came from is rather old, as no one here in Kansai really speaks like this any more.

If you were to say the same thing in the Kansai area　(More specifically Wakayama and south Osaka) nowadays it would go something like this.

> おぇ、くっせなぁ。。。　わし、マスクなかったらブタ小屋ちかよれやんわ
>
> ahh, this stinks...  There is no way I could go near a pig pen
> without a mask.

Same sentence in what Kantou region would say.

> うわぁ、くっさいな。。。　おれ、マスクなかったらブタ小屋にはちかよれない

Comment: Tough crowd here at the Japanese forum.

Comment: DVしたの私じゃないですけど、関西人の目から見て「くっせなぁ。。。わし、マスクなかったらブタ小屋ちかよれやんわ」は、大阪・京都辺りの関西弁としてはちょっと変だと思います。どこら辺の関西弁を想定していらっしゃいますか？

Comment: @chocolate, 和歌山弁ですよ。和歌山は関西じゃないんですか？あなたは大阪・京都辺りだけを関西だと思っていらっしゃるのですか？

Comment: 私はそうは思っていないから、「どこらへんですか」とお聞きしたわけなんですけど…。それじゃ、「和歌山弁だ」ってひとこと回答に書き添えたほうがいいかもしれませんよね。しつこいようですが、私はDVしてませんけど、大阪弁辺りの関西弁しか知らない人は、間違っていると思ってDVしているのかもしれませんから。

Comment: @chocolate.　すみませんでした。追加します。ありがとうございました。